# Why does the AWS OpsWorks "register" command require these permissions to run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-opsworks

Why does the `aws opsworks register` command require [these](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/registered-instances-register-registering-template.html) permissions to run?:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "opsworks:AssignInstance",
        "opsworks:CreateStack",
        "opsworks:CreateLayer",
        "opsworks:DeregisterInstance",
        "opsworks:DescribeInstances",
        "opsworks:DescribeStackProvisioningParameters",
        "opsworks:DescribeStacks",
        "opsworks:UnassignInstance"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:AddUserToGroup",
        "iam:CreateAccessKey",
        "iam:CreateGroup",
        "iam:CreateUser",
        "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
        "iam:PassRole",
        "iam:PutUserPolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Perhaps I am being over-cautious, but it seems to me that any policy that grants full permissions to `iam:CreateUser` and `iam:PutUserPolicy` would basically be a huge security hole, as this level of access would give you the rights to create an admin user at any time.

Am I missing something? Or can the above policy be made more secure and still work with OpsWorks?

Answer (score 0):

Those IAM permissions are used to create an IAM user for the instance, and those permissions only used once for `aws opsworks register` command.

It's a little bit oeverkill to have all those permission just for one command once but it's more for simplify the instance registration configuration. If you have concern about the permissions, you could register instance from your workstation instead of inside instance with instance profile, something like `aws opsworks register --infrastructure-class ec2 --region us-east-1 --stack-id ac95d52c-3f4d-4452-b134-b44f6b4c4f02 --ssh-username [username] --ssh-private-key [key-path] i-050e2a8c`. In this way, only your workstation need such IAM permissions.